# I am having an issue with preparing Dataframes for a machine learning model

Tags: pandas

When I call the group by function with the training data I retain all the original columns but when I call it with the data that I want to apply the model to it drops two columns.
There are 3 scans for each plotted find number therefore I am trying to group by the plotted find and Assemblage for all three scans and take the mean.
This is the code:

```
SC = df1
groupSC = SC.groupby(["PlottedFind","Assemblage"], as_index=False).mean()
SC2 = df2
groupSC2 = SC2.groupby(["PlottedFind","Assemblage"], as_index=False).mean()
```

df1 column names: `['PlottedFind', 'Scan', 'Assemblage', 'L', 'A', 'B', 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700]`

df2 column names: `['PlottedFind', 'Scan', 'Assemblage', 'L', 'A', 'B', 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700]`

groupSC column names:`['PlottedFind', 'Assemblage', 'L', 'A', 'B', 400, 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700]`

groupSC2 column names:

```
['PlottedFind', 'Assemblage', 'A', 'B', 410, 420, 430, 440, 450, 460, 470, 480, 490, 500, 510, 520, 530, 540, 550, 560, 570, 580, 590, 600, 610, 620, 630, 640, 650, 660, 670, 680, 690, 700]
```

I don't understand why the groupSC2 drops the L and 400 columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have non numeric values in columns 'L' and '400' of `df2`. However the behavior is different depending on the version of Pandas:

Consider this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PlottedFind': list('AABBCC'),
                   'Assemblage': list('XXYYZZ'),
                   'L': [0, 1, 2, 3, '4', 5],  # bad value
                   'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
```

```
>>> df  # L looks like fine!
  PlottedFind Assemblage  L  A  B
0           A          X  0  0  0
1           A          X  1  1  1
2           B          Y  2  2  2
3           B          Y  3  3  3
4           C          Z  4  4  4
5           C          Z  5  5  5

>>> df.dtypes
PlottedFind    object
Assemblage     object
L              object  # <- object even if values seem to be numeric
A               int64
B               int64
dtype: object
```

Try `groupby_mean` on different versions of Pandas.

- **Pandas 1.4.4**

```
>>> df.groupby(['PlottedFind', 'Assemblage'], as_index=False).mean()

  PlottedFind Assemblage    A    B
0           A          X  0.5  0.5
1           B          Y  2.5  2.5
2           C          Z  4.5  4.5
```

- **Pandas 1.5.3**

```
>>> df.groupby(['PlottedFind', 'Assemblage'], as_index=False).mean()

FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.mean is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only columns which should be valid for the function.

  PlottedFind Assemblage    A    B
0           A          X  0.5  0.5
1           B          Y  2.5  2.5
2           C          Z  4.5  4.5
```

- **Pandas 2.1.2**

```
>>> df.groupby(['PlottedFind', 'Assemblage'], as_index=False).mean()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
...
TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]
```